# sbt Scalatest NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, sbt, noclassdeffounderror, scalatest

I am trying to run a test using `sbt` and I am being thrown the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class`.

My environment is: `Unix`, `sbt`, `scalatest`.

I have pointed the `scalalibrary` to the one which I installed instead of the IntelliJ plugin(which dint work either)

Project Build File

```
name := "PleaseGod"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.35.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.1"
```

Please refer the following link for the project structure : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIwQ1.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I hit this exact same problem after generating a scala project from a giter8 template (`fayimora/basic-scala-project` [listed here)](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/wiki/giter8-templates)

The problem was that the Scala version was `2.11.5` but the ScalaTest version was `2.10`. Contents for `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

After I changed it to `"scalatest_2.11` it compiled and executed tests as expected.

I see that your configuration is using `scalatest_2.11` so I suspect one of your other dependencies has a similar Scala version conflict?

I also added a `project/build.properties` file that explicitly set the sbt version to `0.13.8`

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```